# How to pass array of objects to asp.net core controller via ajax

Tags: arrays, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor

I am working on a complex form with different sections that are pulling data from different sources. the form has checkboxes, select options, and input forms.

There form has dynamic input fields. So I decided to get all the input fields and serialize has seen in the code below. I was able to pull all the input data.

I tried dictionary and parameter type but still getting the empty or null parameter.

I have tried some suggestions here on StackOverflow but non has been able to fix the issue.

When I passed this to the controller I got null/empty

How can I pass the array of objects to the controller?

[image: Array of objects]

Controller image below

[image: Controller image]

Code below

```
$(function () {
    $("#btn-down-save").on("click", function () {;
        var serialised = $('form').serializeArray();
        console.log("serialised data", serialised);

        $.ajax({
            "type": "POST",
            "url": "/MerchantFeeSetup/CreateMerchantFee",
            "dataType": "json",
            "contentType": "application/json",
            "data": JSON.stringify(serialised),
            success: function (result) { }
        })
    })
})
```

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CreateMerchantFee([FromBody] List<string> collection)
{
}
```

Comment: looks like you are senduing the wrong data type, either write a parser on send back a string array instead of an object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

Create view model

```
public class NameValue
{
public string Value {get; set;}
public string Name {get; set;}
}
```

fix ajax

```
  $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/MerchantFeeSetup/CreateMerchantFee",
            data: {"collection":serialised},
            success: function (result) { }
        })
```

and remove [FromBody]

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CreateMerchantFee( List<NameValue> collection)
{
}
```