# how to extract keys and values from a list of object in asp.net core c#

Tags: c#, list, dictionary, asp.net-core

I passed an array of object key-value pairs from the frontend to the controller. refer here for clarification [Pass array of objects to asp.net core controller via ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67870420/how-to-pass-array-of-objects-to-asp-net-core-controller-via-ajax/67871285#67871285)

The list is going to different tables, I want to loop the list and check those that start with "product" and save to the Product table, then those start with "fee" to Fee table etc.

I am thinking of putting it in a dictionary to get the keys and the values, with that I can assign each value to Project object and Fee object.

[image]

```
        public ActionResult CreateSetUp(List<MerchantInfoSetUpViewModel> collection)
        {
            try
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < collection.Count; i++)
                {
                    var eachName = collection[i].Name; 
                    if (eachName.Substring(0, 7) == "product")
                    {                        
                        //List<string> allValues = (from productFeeValue in collection select productFeeValue.Value).Distinct().ToList();                        //List<string> keyList = new List<string>(this.co)
                        ConfigureMerchantFee configureMerchantFee = new ConfigureMerchantFee
                        {        
                            //MerchantId = allValues.                       
                        };
                        productRepository.AddOneEntity(collection[i].Value);
                    }
                    if (eachName.Substring(0, 8) == "product-")
                    {
                    } 
                    else { }              
                }                
                
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));            
            }catch{                
                return null;            
            }        
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to convert `List<MerchantInfoSetUpViewModel>` to `Dictionary<string, string>`.You can use the following code:

```
Dictionary<string, string> d = collection
             .ToDictionary(k => k.Name, v => v.Value);
```

result:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I was able to achieve this by passing the serialized list to a dictionary.

```
var listObj = new List<object>
{
    new {Name="productTest", Value="test"},
    new {Name="productTest2", Value="test2"},
    new {Name="productTest3", Value="test3"}
};

var list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MerchantInfoSetUpViewModel>>(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(listObj));

var dictionary = list.ToDictionary(x => x.Name, x => x.Value);

TestProjectForDb testProjectForDb = new TestProjectForDb
{
  productTest = dictionary["productTest"],
  productTest1 = dictionary["productTest2"],
  productTest2 = dictionary["productTest3"]
 };

 var result = Repository.AddEntity(testProjectForDb);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert list of object to json string then convert to you model. Let's assume you have a model like this:

```
public class MerchantInfoSetUpViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

And do in this way by using `Newtonsoft.json`:

```
 var listObj = new List<object>
        {
            new {Name="productTest", Value="test"},
            new {Name="productTest2", Value="test2"}
        };

        var list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MerchantInfoSetUpViewModel>>(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(listObj));
```

Now there is list of model and can iterate over them.